# Typescript fs.writeFileSync failed wit Value is not an object

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, k6

Would you please help to understand what is wrong with my entry parameters to fs.writeFileSync which causes ERRO - 'Value is not an object'

k6 script:

```
import { sleep, check } from 'k6';
import { Options } from 'k6/options';
import http from 'k6/http';
import { createNodeJson } from './test_data/create_node_json';
import { CreateNode } from './test_data/create_node_json';
import { uuidv4 } from "https://jslib.k6.io/k6-utils/1.4.0/index.js"
import { writeFile, writeFileSync } from 'fs';


const url = 'https://test.com/create';

export let options:Options = {
  vus: 1,
  duration: '2s'
};

 export default () => {
  const json = uuidUpdate(createNodeJson);
  console.log("JSON used:" + JSON.stringify(json));

  const response = http.post(url, JSON.stringify(json), {
    headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer asdasdasdasdasdasdad',
      'Accept': '*/*',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
      'Connection': 'keep-alive'

  },
  });
  
  console.log("Response: " +  response.body);


  check(response, {
    'Response status is 201 HTTP': () => response.status === 201
  });
  sleep(2);

  console.log("Saving uuid into file...");
  // writeFile("test.txt", json.id, function(error){
  //   if (error) {
  //     console.log(error);
  //   }
  // }
  // );

  // writeFileSync("test.txt", "asdasdasd", {
  //   encoding: "utf8",
  //   flag: "a+",
  //   mode: 0o666
  // });

  writeFileSync("test.txt", "asdasdasd");


};

function uuidUpdate(json: CreateNode): CreateNode {
  json.id = uuidv4();
  return json;
}
```

I run script like:

```
yarn webpack
k6 run .\dist\myscript.js
```

Error:

```
....
INFO[0000] JSON used:{"id":"7cef4aed-b7da-4587-ba15-0575677ed90c"}  source=console
INFO[0002] Saving uuid into file...                      source=console
ERRO[0002] TypeError: Value is not an object: undefined                                                                                                                                                          running at post_200_create_node_test (webpack://typescript/./src/myscript.ts:55:16(75))  executor=constant-vus scenario=default source=stacktrace

     ✓ Response status is 201 HTTP
```

ts.config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "removeComments": false,

    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,

    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,

    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,

    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
  }
}
```

P.S. The same error is thrown when I call writeFileSync with three parameters:

```
  writeFileSync("test.txt", "asdasdasd", {
    encoding: "utf8",
    flag: "a+",
    mode: 0o666
  });
```

Comment: I don't know, what your ts.config looks like, could you please add it to your question? The error probably says "undefined", because you only give two parameters inside `writeFileSync`. Have you tried giving an empty option parameter (an empty object) inside `writeFileSync`?

Comment: You are passing an `undefined` value as second parameter to `writeFileSync` ... So that error is not caused by the code you are showing

Comment: @Geshode no, it has nothing to do with a missing options object ...

Comment: @derpirscher console.log(typeof("asdasdasd")); => "string" . It should not be undefined

Comment: I don't think this is supported in the k6 core, see https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/modules/#bundling-node-modules and https://community.k6.io/t/write-data-to-file/1462/2 (a bit oldish). I would have a look at community extensions like https://github.com/avitalique/xk6-file.

Comment: @Imma Thanks for directing me to this. And this restriction is bad, seems I will be thinking of not using k6 at all... IO is generic functionality which to be supported by any framework

Comment: @27P Ah didn't notice you are using k6. Seems that this is an issue/limitation with that runtime. Citing from https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/modules/ "*k6 is not NodeJS, nor is it a browser. Packages that rely on APIs provided by NodeJS, for instance the os and fs modules, will not work in k6. The same goes for browser-specific APIs like the window object.*"

Comment: @derpirscher, thanks a lot. K6 appeared to be quite an immature product )

Comment: @27P I'd recommend you open a feature request in the repo https://github.com/grafana/k6.

Comment: @Imma I also see there is Redis support, so with some effort It can resolve my task to share data between several tests

Comment: @27P k6 is/can be executed on multiple computers to generate even more load. That makes it difficult to have a single "file system". It's not trivial. Why do you need to save a UUID? Could you save the uuid with the end-of-test summary or as part of a tag? I've implemented similar solutions in the past and it worked quite well.

Comment: @knittl I need to save UUID: one test creates something with UUID via API, the sequent test will be using the same UUID to call another API - we test load for flow not just single API. I do not find my case to be exceptional. However, as I mention there is Redis support and I can use it, ...just working with it. P.S. Jmeter support IO - why the state of the art k6.io should not do the same under the hood?

Comment: @27P you don't need multiple tests to test a flow. A single test can execute multiple steps. Also look into [scenarios](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/scenarios/)

Comment: @knittl Thanks a lot for the link, I will take a look, it might help me to tackle my challenge. Just took a peek at it....so we might have multiple scenarios in one test - will it have separate metrics for each scenario or summary covering all of them?

Comment: @27P you get both: by default overall metrics, but you can easily add metrics for each scenario by defining (empty) thresholds for each scenario.